# How to keep data synced between development and production databases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-6, pgadmin

Update:

People have raised some good questions about my site and workload so I thought some addition information would be helpful.

My site has 1200+ plants in a garden, with multiple tables and dozens of fields. Besides basic spelling corrections other attributes may need to be changed (location, size, alive/dead to name a few). We will then be adding addition plants thought a to be developed (local access only, not on the web).

We currently manually enter changes in both database but this seems impractical as we are likely looking at hundreds of changes across the database not to mention the addition of new plants.

Background:

We are starting to look at a major update to our database which will include correcting spelling, changing some attributes, and adding new items.  To me, it seems like the development database is the correct place to start these changes, and then have the migrate to the production server automatically so both have more or less the same data. I realize that the development and production databases are supposed to be kept separate, but as these changes are going to be done mostly by others I'm looking for a way to keep the development and production databases in sync in more automated fashion.

System architecture (all systems are Ubuntu if that matters):

- Data server running postgresql Development server, mostly off
  Production server Workstation (I use pgadmin among other tools to
  access the various servers)

Goal:

I would prefer live syncing between the databases, but I'm ok with either hourly or daily updated if that makes it easier.

On the other hand, maybe I'm thinking about this too literally and all the changes should be made live to the production database and the development database should be updated only when the development server is turned on.

Comment: How do you refresh your dev database now, and why won't that still work for this particular refresh?

Comment: It sounds like you are making multiple changes at once. How critical is this app? Correcting spelling errors is much different problem than changing attributes or "adding some items" (what does that mean exactly?). Are you talking about making the changes in Dev and pushing them up to the production server? That sound like a terrible idea if true. Each change process should have it's own plan with roll-back contingency etc.

Comment: Unless you really want to test your disaster recovery methods don't directly connect the dev database to the production database. For this sort of thing I use [Sqitch](https://sqitch.org/). It allows you build changes that you can roll out to production after testing on dev.

Comment: One of the databases I use `Sqitch` on is for a greenhouse operation that has had upwards of 8000(not all in production at same time) different plant varieties  in it. Over the years I have migrated it through many changes, some quite extensive, using unlinked dev and production databases. As long as there is a documented well laid out change procedure I don't see that being an issue in your case.

Comment: You should really consider that dev, test, and production are just the pre-configured enviroments and that you can (and should) add additional environments when needed. For example in this case you could setup a staging environment for example where you work on a copy of the production data.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I think Sqitch sounds like the solution I'm looking for.  I'd love to mark it as the answer, but if I remember correctly it needs to be an answer not just a comment (it's been a long time since I've been on Stack Overflow). Funny you're a plant person also,

Comment: Well the question was not actually [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) per SO guidelines, therefore I will leave it as just comments to keep from annoying those who care about those things. Actually I'm a fisheries biologist who fell into the plant world. Also in the its a small world category,  I'm North of you in Bellingham and I used to deliver plants across E & W Washington.

Answer (score 0):

**Step#1**: I think the way to go is creating a script that will apply the desired changes to the dev environment first. You can validate the results and proceed to *Step#2* if everything looks good. Otherwise, just restore prod data to dev environment again, adjust/fix the script and repeat until satisfied.

**Step#2**: Now run the same script in another (i.e. pre-prod) environment against the data *from* production, e.g. most recent copy of production data. Note that the outcome of Step#1 may be not accurate as many developers/features may have modified the dev environment data, and you script will produce different results depending on which version of data it's applied to. So for better confidence, you want an environment with locked write access to data from prod that has just been restore to pre-prod. Proceed if satisfied.

**Step#3**: Then, finally run against production, and do some testing.

*Hope this helps.*